# Windows 7 Ultimate - Cannot detect my network

Tags: windows-7, networking

Recently upgraded to Windows 7 Ultimate, but frustratingly i cannot detect my network.

Uninstalled and reinstalled drivers so many times, got a red x next to my network connections in my start bar. Everything in device manager saying the device is running fine. I've got an Intel 82566DC -2 Gigabit Network Connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste the PCI\VEN string of your NIC into this website: http://www.devid.info/sv/ and try the suggested driver.

Comment: Thanks, how do i find out the PCI/VEN string? Sorry no idea about hardware problems lol

Comment: Click the start menu then type devmgmt.msc in the search field. Right click your network adapter and click properties. Click Details. From the drop-down list, pick Hardware Ids. Right click the first string and click Copy. Paste it into the website and click ok. http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/934/devmgmt.png

Answer (score 0):

I read that you've tried to uninstall/reinstall drivers, but have you tried the methods suggested on this page?

> http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/21418-solution-unknown-network-no-connection-inter.html

The only other thing I could think of is to do a clean install of Windows 7 and seeing if that would detect your network. Hope you find these suggestions helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The thing is its not even detecting it at all, tried lots of diffrent drivers even tried uninstalling and letting windows install, still no luck.